# sending timer events in Esper 4.8

Tags: java, esper

I have a csv file as input adapter and I want to send the event from csv file every second. For the example, I have A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, and B3. I want send A1, A2, and A3 in the first second and for B1, B2, and B3 sent in the second two. In this reference http://esper.codehaus.org/esperio-4.0.0/doc/reference/en/html_single/index.html#csv-timer there is a explanation about sending timer events. Does it mean for send the event according with the timestamp that have been set in csv file? If true, how to use it? I have read this reference but I don't understand how to use it. If the reference can't use for sending event per second, is there a another way to set event so can sent every second?

Answer (score 2):

You can programatically control the clock in the esper engine by sending time events in addition to your data events.

```
// Esper Configuration
ClassLoader cl = EpnService.class.getClassLoader();
URL configURL = cl.getResource("aem.esper.cfg.xml");
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.configure(configURL);

// Obtain esper service instance
EPServiceProvider esperSvc_ = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("TEST", config);

// Disable internal engine timer (if not already done so in esper config file)
TimerControlEvent controlEvent = new TimerControlEvent(TimerControlEvent.ClockType.CLOCK_EXTERNAL);
esperSvc_.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(controlEvent);

// Set engine time
long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // or use some other time from your data
CurrentTimeEvent timeEvent1 = new CurrentTimeEvent(timeInMillis);
esperSvc_.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(timeEvent1);

// Inject events into engine
Object eventObject1 = new Object();
esperSvc_.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(eventObject1);

// Fast forward engine time
timeInMillis += 1000; // Add 1 second
CurrentTimeEvent timeEvent2 = new CurrentTimeEvent(timeInMillis);
esperSvc_.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(timeEvent2);

// Inject more events into engine
Object eventObject2 = new Object();
esperSvc_.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(eventObject2);
```